# iText7 change form text colour

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrofields

I use iText7 and Java to populate pdf forms. The pdf modules were created with Adobe program and I use a custom font, I embed into the finished PDF.
If I try to add some coloured text to the pdf, the entire program crashes. How can I do ?

Here is the code I use to colour the text:

```
String fontPath = this.getClass().getResource("RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf").getPath();
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
PdfFont regularFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, true);
fields.get("scadenza_r").setValue("Scadenza:", regularFont, regularFontSize).setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

And here is the exception it throws:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Dictionary doesn't have supported font data.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:105)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.getFontAndSize(PdfFormField.java:2431)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.regenerateField(PdfFormField.java:1775)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setColor(PdfFormField.java:2170)
at com.lgs.bl.web.invoices.pdf.InvoicePdfCreate.getInvoicePdf(InvoicePdfCreate.java:104)
at com.lgs.bl.web.invoices.ListInvoicePage$12$2$1.write(ListInvoicePage.java:310)
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ResourceStreamResource$1.writeData(ResourceStreamResource.java:192)
at org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.respond(AbstractResource.java:659)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceStreamRequestHandler.respond(ResourceStreamRequestHandler.java:139)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:97)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1584)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1228)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:318)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried also this, but the result is the same:

```
PdfTextFormField tf = (PdfTextFormField) fields.get("numeroRiga_l");
tf.setValue("#", boldFont, boldFontSize);
tf.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found the color apllies correctly if i set it first, and after set the Font, and after the font size.
In other words I have to do the transformations sequentially, and not inside the same method.

Instead of :

```
fields.get("scadenza_r").setValue("Scadenza:", regularFont, regularFontSize).setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I have to type :

```
fields.get("scadenza_r").setValue("Scadenza:").setColor(Color.Blue).setFont(regularFont).setFontSize(regularFontSize);
```

Comment: In addition, I found I had to modify the fields text colour from inside my PDF Editor, which I used to edit and position the fields graphically. 
Probably that application is not fully compatible with iText Library